# exchange columns in numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix of shape m,n.
Now, I want to exchange first column with last, second column with second last, third column with third last and so on..

Is there a "numpy" way to do this?

Right now, I am looping thru half of the num_cols and exchanging the columns.

Comment: How important is the concept of 'exchange'?  The answer using `::-1` technically doesn't exchange anything, it just looks at (returns) the columns in reverse order.  It's a slicing method that applies to lists as well as to arrays.  For most purposes that is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Use [numpy slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) to reverse the column order in your array:

```
my_array = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]])
print(my_array[:, ::-1])
```

**Output**

```
[[ 4  3  2  1]
 [ 8  7  6  5]
 [12 11 10  9]
 [16 15 14 13]]
```

A typical slice is of the form `start:stop:step`. The x-dimension slice, `:`, by default, selects *all* of the rows. The y-dimension slice, `::-1`, selects all of the columns, but with a step size of -1, so places them in reverse order, hence swapping the order of the columns as desired.